# Inheritance of animation keyframes of element

Tags: css, animation, inheritance, less, less-mixins

I've got an element `.shake` and when it's `:hover` an animation starts. I need to inherit the shake element properties and its animation `:hover` effect.

I've got

```
.inherit-shake {
   .shake;
}
```

It doesn't work because `.inherit-shake` just inherits the primary `.shake` properties but its `:hover` animation.

Is there a way to do that using Less?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the rules for `.shake` and `.shake:hover` were written like in the below snippet then your current code should work as-is.

```css
.inherit-shake {.shake;}
.shake{
    a:a;
    &:hover{b:b;}
}
```

However, I think they are written like below and that is the reason why the `:hover` rules don't get applied to `.inherit-shape` selector.

```css
.inherit-shake {.shake;}
.shake{a:a;}
.shake:hover{b:b;}
```

---

The best solution would be to use the model mentioned in the first snippet. However, if you can't change the source mixin's for whatever reason then the best would be to make use of [`extend`](http://lesscss.org/features/#extend-feature-extend-syntax) function with [`all`](http://lesscss.org/features/#extend-feature-extend-all-) keyword like in the below snippet:

```css
.inherit-shake {&:extend(.shake all);}
.shake{a:a;}
.shake:hover{b:b;}
```

The `all` keyword within `extend` function would make sure that `.inherit-shake:hover` gets the same properties as applicable for `.shake:hover`. The compiled CSS output would be like below:

```css
.shake, .inherit-shake {a: a;}
.shake:hover, .inherit-shake:hover {b: b;}
```

Added advantage of using `extend` function is that it would automatically group selectors (like in the output shown above).